# TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined onEdit @ macros.gs:6

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this code to move row from one sheet to another with the data validation "Sold" but when I try to execute this code it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined onEdit  @ macros.gs:6

```
    function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
// target sheet of move to named Sheet2
// test column with yes is col 6 or F
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Pioneer Powersports" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Sold") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sold Item");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `event` variable in your function means you are implementing  [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite). To make onEdit(e) works, you must change a value in your spreadsheet.

If you run it on the editor, no value was passed down on the event variable, which causes the property 'source' of undefined.

Reference:

[Google Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)